# What would be the best word/way to describe the differences in two deep learning models (deep, wide, shallow, big or small model?)

Tags: deep-learning, terminology

I did experiments using a backbone deep network. I took it as it is and then I decreased the number of filters and did some other experiments. Note that, I did not change the number of layers of the original backbone network. Note that the original model requires a very high number of parameters while the new one (in which I changed only the number of filters in convolutional layers) requires very less parameters. Say that the original model is **model A**, and the new model is **model B**.

While trying to report/write experiments, I think I can not say that model A is a deep model and model B is a ***shallower*** model since I did not change the deepness of model A to design model B. What word should I use to describe model B? Saying ***small*** model sounds weird I think but I could not find the right word. Could anyone help with this please?

To be more precise, suppose that this is my original model, model A architecture (designing the model, before training)

[image: model A]

I decreased the number of filters in convolutional layer of model A from 24 to 12 to obtain model B architecture(designing the model, before training). Then, model B is

[image: model B]

Model images are created using [online tool](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html)

Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156844/755, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/117767/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: The title should be a short summary; it doesn't need to be a complete sentence.  Please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise the post so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the community will consider requests for us to propose a word to describe things to be on-topic.  If you're not sure how to describe it in a paper, you can always explain multiple words what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your warnings. I deleted the other post and paid attention to what you said about the title, and edit @D.W. Considering my question, I do not know if a word exists to describe this. I, of course, explained it with multiple words, but I wanted to know the terminology for this if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Describing Model B as the ***smaller*** model seems perfectly acceptable to me. Smaller implies fewer trainable parameters, which describes the model accurately. Obviously, there are a number of ways the model could be smaller; but as long as you describe the differences between the two models when you introduce them, it should be clear what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ended up by explaining what is "small" and "big" model for me then continue with this notation in the rest of report.